# Precompiled Handlebar Inline Templates With Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I know how to precompile my Handlebar templates when I externalize them by having them in a separate file. Lately, I have been shortening my templates and using them inline. For example I have the following Backbone View.

```
var ChosenVehicle = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: "car selection",

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.data = options.chosenData;
  },

  template: Handlebars.compile(
    '<h4 class="number">01</h4>' +
    '<img src="assets/img/cars/{{vehicleSlug}}.jpg" alt="{{vehicle}}">' +
    '<p class="flush">' +
      '<small class="text--center caps">' +
        '{{vehicle}}' +
      '</small>' +
    '</p>'
  ),

  render: function() {
    var chosenCar = _.find(this.model.get("cars"), function(car) {
      return car.id.toString() === this.data.vehicleId;
    }, this);
    this.$el.html(this.template(chosenCar));
    return this;
  }
});
```

What are the performance ramifications using the above and not precompiling the templates? I prefer to have my templates setup above as I find it much easier to read and maintain. Now obviously I am  unable to precompile my template, or is there another solution?

Thanks

Tyrone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you may think this is easier to read and maintain, but it's not. You don't want to open a javascript file to edit your templates/markup; just as you don't want to open CSS to debug Javascript (remember `expression()`?).

The idea is to precompile your template through your build system. This can be easy if you load your template via a requireJs loader plugin; e.g.:

```
template: require("hbs!templates/listItem")
```

You can also checkout how Backbone Boilerplate does it right now: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate (Although, we spoke about going the requireJs plugin road in the near future)

Checkout Github-Viewer for a working example of Backbone Boilerplate templates loading/precompiling: https://github.com/tbranyen/github-viewer

Comment: I have used BBB in a number of projects and love the process, even though the repository has not been updated to the latest version of both Backbone and Backbone Layout Manager. Anyway I was reading Recipes With Backbone. The book uses inline templates throughout. I was also taken aback by it in the beginning, until it forced me to right simple concise views without separating the template from the actual view. I don't necessarily agree with your first statement as your are using javascript to build out your markup.

Comment: If you work in a team, this pattern will become problematic (with frontend devs, Integrators, designers, etc). Also, think about the fact that most editors won't add any value for inline HTML strings, which is not true if they're in separated files: code coloration, intellisence, etc. BTW, this bad pattern is cited as is in _[Maintainable Javascript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025245.do)_

Comment: Ok will then have to agree. Got in touch with the guys who wrote Recipes With Backbone and stated they wrote in such a way that it would be easier for the reader to understand. they do not use the above pattern when building apps. However, in the book it states 'Since the template in this case is small, we are not sacrificing much in the way of readability by including it directly in the view class. Not only do we have the template available without jarring <script> tags getting in the way, but no searching is required to find the template. The template is right in the Backbone view itself.'